# Problema con WebView Android

Tags: android-studio, webview

Hola tengo el siguiente problema y la verdad ya estoy mareado de buscarle la solucion, quizas alguno me ayude o identifique el problema que no me doy cuenta, tengo un WebView en mi app que abre el enlace que esta en el codigo mas abajo, hasta ahi todo bien, el problema reside que la web que abre tiene archivos PDF para visualizar y al darles click para abrir no hace nada, pero si me deja navegar por el menu de la pagina a la que abro en un principio, solo los PDF no reaccionan.

```
package app.kampai.kampai.appministeriodelaproduccion;


import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.example.kampai.appministeriodelaproduccion.R;


public class estadistica extends AppCompatActivity {


    ProgressBar progressBar;
    WebView mywebview;
    String url = "https://estadistica.lapampa.gob.ar/agricola-ganadero.html";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_estadistica);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.prgestadistica);
        mywebview = findViewById(R.id.webview_estadistica);
        mywebview.loadUrl(url);


        WebSettings settings = mywebview.getSettings();

        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        settings.supportZoom();
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

        mywebview.clearHistory();
        mywebview.clearCache(true);

        mywebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }



            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Los pdf donde se encuentran, es un url o en la misma página html? te sugiero especificar esto, revisa [ask] saludos.

Comment: No es posible abrir un PDF en un webview debes de usar la ruta de Google Drive o una librería externa para renderizarlo

Comment: Como comenta aitorlv actualmente no es posible cargar un pdf en un WebView nativamente, revisa otra opción como el visor de Google Drive  @LuisGuzman

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir un pdf dentro de un WebView considera usar otras opciones, por ejemplo:

#### Para abrir un archivo .PDF dentro de un `WebView`, como opción puedes usar el visor de Google Drive, este es un ejemplo:

```
     WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    
            }
        });
        
         //Url Ejemplo:
        String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
    
         //Carga url de .PDF en WebView  mediante Google Drive Viewer. 
        webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```